# Pyglet window does not reopen after being run

Tags: python, pyglet

I made a Snake game program and I've made a function called `Starting_screen()` that opens a window with labels and sprites that shows the starting menu of the game where the player can choose to start a new game, check the leader board, or quit the game. 
 
My main problem is that after the player finishes a game of Snake, I want the program to return to the main menu but it just hangs after the game exits. I've tried putting `print` statements within the `Starting_Screen()` function and it actually prints twice, indicating that it re-enters the function but does not open the window again. The flow of the program looks somewhat like this (in simpler sense):
The game is being run by `main.py` that has:

```
import interface
import engine

interface.main()
print('outside the interface.main()')
interface.main()
```

As you can see I've just initially tried to put two `interface.main()` functions so that I can check if the program runs the second one. It actually prints the statement which indicates it exits the function.

The `interface.main()` runs only the `Starting_screen()`, and the `Starting_screen()` looks like this (simplified):

```
def Starting_screen():

    print('inside starting screen')
    window = pyglet.window.Window()
    some_text = pyglet.text.Label()
    some_image = pyglet.image.load()

    @window.event
    def on_draw():
        window.clear()
        some_text.draw()
        some_image.draw()

    @window.event
    def on_key_press(symbol,modifier):
        if symbol == key.P:
            window.close()
            engine.main()

    pyglet.app.run()
```

and the `engine.main()` just runs the game (using `pygame`) until the player loses and it will `pygame.display.quit()` that will terminate the `engine.main()` function and returns to the `Starting_screen()` which in turn terminates the function.

I was hoping it would open the main menu window again but it does not. But interestingly enough, it runs `print('inside starting screen')` *twice*, indicating that it runs the function again, but it does not open the window like what would normally happen when it was run for the first time.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I tested it on LInux Mint but without `engine.main()` and it shows window again. Did you tested it without `engine.main()`? Maybe `pygame` makes some problem.

Comment: Yeah, still the same.

Comment: It prints this `inside starting screen`
`out of first interface.main()`
`inside starting screen`.

Comment: try to remove `import engine`. I tested without this module. If it will still not show window then I don't have more ideas.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.